# pyodbc column name as variable

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

Instead of editing the sql-string when i want to change which column to write to i want to use a variable.. This seems to work. I get no error, but the database is not updated... What is wrong with this?

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=FreeTDS;SERVER=dkvmsql08;PORT=1433;DATABASE=dingdong_test;UID=dac\svc-dingdong;PWD=c90346KJHjkhg&%dad742210a3d6fd4436c;T$
cur = cnxn.cursor()

name = Dennis
cur.execute("UPDATE dbo.timestamp  set cur.execute("UPDATE dbo.test  set ?=1 where id=?",name, row.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no explicit commit statement in your code and the connect call doesn't include `autocommit=True`, so try adding `cnxn.commit()` to the end of your code. :)

Answer (score 0):

Query parameters can be used to specify the *values* of columns but not the column *names*, so you would need to do something like the following:

```python
name = "yourColumnName"
sql = "UPDATE dbo.timestamp SET [{}]=1 WHERE ID=?".format(name)
cur.execute(sql, row.id)
cur.commit()
```