# pyodbc: cannot update table using string variables for column name and value

Tags: python, pyodbc

I am trying to update an SQL table where the column name and the actual are "unknown"/strings. I get the column names from quandl and use the same names in the SQL table.

The code below should show an example of what I am trying to do:

```
data = quandl.get("EOD/PG", trim_start = "2011-12-12", trim_end = "2017-10-15", authtoken=quandl.ApiConfig.api_key)

data = data.reset_index()
da = list(data.columns.values)
for row in data.itertuples():
    i = 2
    while i < len(da):
        price = row[i:i+1]
        price, = price
        col = da[i]
        i += 1
        cur.execute("update PG set ? = (?)", (col, price))
```

However, apparently the "price" isn't working and I get the following error:

> pyodbc.DataError: ('22003', '[22003] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver][SQL Server]Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to
>   data type nvarchar. (8115) (SQLExecDirectW)')

If I manually set the price = 55 then the table updates. That confuses me because when when I print the price (using my code) I get a float value.

So I am not sure how to fix this. Any help would be welcommed.

Comment: `set ? = ` can't work because your can't parameterize column names. You'll need to `format` the column names in.

Comment: `cur.execute("update PG set {} = (?)".format(col), (price,))`. If `col` comes from outside, you'll have to sanitise it yourself to stop SQL injection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pyodbc column name as variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21858012/2144390)